# Azure App Gateway backend settings for load balancing multiple ports on same backend pool

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have 3 Azure VMs which run web app deployed to Weblogic. There are 3 JVMs ( web apps ) in each server running on ports 8001,8002,8003. Routing rule allows only 1 backend setting. In this case, how can I load balance all 9 JVMs with one listener? This feature is available almost in all Load balancers I have worked with including App LB on AWS and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

If this is not possible, at the risk of sounding stupid can I create 3 backend settings each for 8001,8002 and 8003, create 3 listeners(multi-site, listening on port 443) and rule which maps to this backend settings with backend pool as the Azure VMs and then use these listeners with FQDN as another backend pool for my final load balanced site.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently got the same problem.  My thought was to use AppGW as the front end for users with Azure LB as the backend pool for AppGW, and then use Azure LB to distribute the load to the VMs/ports.  eg If there are 3 JVM ports per VM then the Azure LB would have 3 Frontend IPs (1 per backend JVM port) all using a common frontend port (eg 80) so that AppGW can connect to the LB on a single port.  Each Frontend in the LB would have 1 backend port defined (eg 8001 for 1st frontend, 8002 for 2nd frontend, etc) to then connect to the backend JVM.  The Azure LB would load balance across the VMs.  Yet to be tested though...  and still not sure how to handle session persistence and timeouts.

Comment: You are right, the only problem is the cookie based affinity which I really need for my App, Azure LB is L4 and it doesnt support it, I think it supports IP and Protocol based persistence which may be useless if using App GW in front, the client IP would always be the same. Looks Azure Front door  might help, I am planning to try this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/media/quickstart-create-front-door/front-door-add-a-backend.png. as per this screenshot, you might be able to same host ( with IP or FQDN ) multiple times to a backend pool itself

Comment: or may be another App GW instead of Azure LB with multi-site listeners one for each port and add these as backend end to the main App GW. I tried to do this in same App GW but I ran into an issue and I see a 502 Error

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while and I just realized I didn't update this question with how I solved this problem.

Since binding port binding is at the IP Address, I can have multiple Web Servers ( JVM ) using the same port if I assign multiple IP Address and bind each JVM to one IP address and define these IP Addresses in the App GW backend. So If I have 3 JVMs on the same server, each JVM will listen on port 443 binding on different IP address and all these 3 IP Addresses will be added to backend pool.